# I want add a window Alert before I reset the style I already use?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, sweetalert

I have a button here with a simple CSS. what I want is, when I hit on that button to reset my style. I use it, I need to add a sweet alert before pressing the button.

```
<button class="reset-option">Reset Options</button>
```

```
document.querySelector(".reset-option").onclick = function () {

  localStorage.clear();
  window.location.reload();
};
```

What I want is, add this alert to handle it with javascript.

```
swal({
  title: "OOPS !",
  text: "You Want To Resat Your Style!",
  icon: "warning",
});
```

I tried to do this but it didn't work.

```
let resetOption = document.querySelector(".reset-option");

resetOption.onclick = function () {

  if (resetOption.window === reload()) {
    swal({
      title: "OOPS !",
      text: "You Want To Resat Your Style!",
      icon: "warning",
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have only one `onclick` handler per element. So here, the second overwrites the first.

Also, Swal returns a promise to handle the result. What is below is real close to the example found [here](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#confirm-dialog).

I suggest:

```js
document.querySelector(".reset-option").onclick = function () {
  
  swal.fire({
    title: "OOPS !",
    text: "You Want To Resat Your Style!",
    icon: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      console.log("confirmed");
      //localStorage.clear();
      //window.location.reload();
    }else{
      console.log("canceled")
    }
  })
    
  
};
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/10.12.5/sweetalert2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/10.12.5/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>

<button class="reset-option">Reset Options</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show an alert to user before hit the button, you can add mouse hover event to your button.

```
var event = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
  'view': window,
  'bubbles': true,
  'cancelable': true
});
document.querySelector(".reset-option").onclick = function () {

  localStorage.clear();
  window.location.reload();
 
};
var cc=document.querySelector(".reset-option") 
cc.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
     //your alert code here
     alert('Before hit button');
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure the user will finally be able to click the button due to the mouseover event that always will trow the alert... Have you tested this?

Comment: you can remove mouse over event handler after it is popped up. check it https://jsfiddle.net/Lbuh6y70/